# Adding joomla's default toolbar in a component view page

Tags: component, php, joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, mvc

I am developing a mvc component for both joomla 2.5 and 3.In many components i saw they added joomla's default command buttons like new, edit, publish, trash, options at top of their settings page in admin side. Eg. if one goes components->weblinks->links page, i am talking about those command buttons at top right.

So how do i add those command buttons in my component's settings page? when clicked it would do respective action and show respective view.For instance, if i click "new" button it will display my mvc component's add entry view as it is.

So how could i add fully workable joomla's command buttons in my component's settings page in admin side.

Answer (score 12):

The best practice is to create the `addToolBar()` method inside your View class and then using `JToolBarHelper` class to create command buttons:

```
protected function addToolBar()
{
  JToolBarHelper::addNew('yourcontroller.add');
  JToolBarHelper::editList('yourcontroller.edit');
}
```

So these will call the task/function "add"/"edit" in your specified controller. Then simply call `$this->addToolBar()` in your View's `display()` method.

Reference [Creating a toolbar for your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_toolbar_for_your_component)

Comment: I have only a controller file controller.php in my component and inside it i have a function `function add() { JRequest::setVar('view', 'entry');
JRequest::setVar('layout', 'form');
parent::display(); }` so in my view.html.php file i added  JToolBarHelper::addNewX('controller.add'); then new button appears but when clicked it does not go to my view form instead adds a # to the url

Comment: Try to omit `controller.task` - `JToolBarHelper::addNewX();`

Comment: Added only JToolBarHelper::addNewX(); but not works.

Comment: Then you need to create a proper controller under `controllers` directory. See [Adding backend actions](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_backend_actions)

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure the view that displays the buttons has a form to submit.   The form name should be adminForm. The form should also have a hidden field named task and the dynamically generated token. I cannot recall the API off the top of my head, but something like `JHtml::_('form.token');` (someone please correct this, if I'm mistaken)

This do the trick.

Comment: The problem i found out before was that i was using form name as adminform instead adminForm.it seems joomla kind of case sensitive!

Comment: It's more of a JavaScript thing than Joomla specific. When you click the buttons you are actually triggering a JS submit form function, so if the form can't be found then it quietly fails.